# Transitioning to Ubuntu - Complete Newbie

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I just wanted to ask on what would you recommend. I am casual Windows user and I plan on transitioning to Linux, based on what I've read so far it seems that Ubuntu is a good fit however what I'm planning to do is try it out on my old laptop first, and by old I mean very old, here's the specs of the laptop:

CPU: Intel Celeron M 440 1.86 GHz,
RAM: 2gb ddr2
Video: Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 950

I was wondering on whether what is the best that this laptop can handle. I initially tried to install it using Wubi? I installed the 14.04.6 32-bit but whenever I tried to boot it it goes directly to grub command prompt, I've read on some sources that a reboot should it fix it but to no avail it doesn't so I'm wondering if I did something wrong or is there an incompatibility with Ubuntu and my hardware,

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. I would recommend [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/), [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/), [Ubuntu mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/), [Ubuntu budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/), which are the lightweight distributions of Ubuntu.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Hi thanks, does it matter which version of for example Xubuntu, I saw on the website that the latest release is 18.04. Should I look for their release on when the laptop was release to ensure that the hardware can cope with the OS?

Comment: Check [the system requirements](https://xubuntu.org/requirements/), the minimum is 512mb of ram, I think you'll be ok.

Comment: For installing, you can look at [the official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview).

Comment: @guillermochamorro thanks! That answered my question. Was wondering how can I do an upvote on your comment for future newbies like me that has the same question, it doesn't have the "Up" button like the comment below has.

Comment: @user535733 thank you so much!

Comment: That's not necessary :) If you run into any problem you are welcome to ask again.

Comment: @guillermochamorro That's very nice of you! Thanks again!

Comment: Note that your system has a 32 bit architecture. The last Ubuntu version to support this was 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Wubi is depreciated; a standard install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit from http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386.iso ,  Lubuntu 18.04 http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-i386.iso , MATE 18.04 http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-mate-18.04.4-desktop-i386.iso , or Xubuntu 18.04 https://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/18.04/release/xubuntu-18.04-desktop-i386.iso will be far easier to troubleshoot. Also, we are able to support those specific versions here.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a trial on a PC with the "Live" feature.

With the "Live" feature you will run the OS from the USB stick without installing it to the hard drive.

And if you add "Persistent file" the changes and files you create will remain between reboots.

[Add persistent file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNezh.png)

Ref.: https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you so much I'll try that in a bit once I figure out what flavor is compatible with my hardware